# Is Xcode/swift 1 or 0 indexed?

Tags: arrays, indexing

I've just come from intro to MatLab (1 indexed arrays) and intro to C (0 indexed arrays) before starting an Xcode group project. Is there an industry standard for Xcode to use 1 or 0 indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array behaviour depends on the language you're using. If you're in a Swift or Objective-C based project, arrays are zero-indexed (as well as in most commonly used programming languages).